# Assign value based on filetype

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript, filetype, plugin-ultisnips

I want to assign value based on filetype.

I am using UltiSnips plugin and want to have one set of bindings for one filetype and another set for everything else.

Something like

```
if &ft='vimwiki'
    let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
else
    let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-tab>"
endif
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like the following. In my vimrc (or a `plugin` file, `:help load-plugins`; I often use `~/.vim/after/plugin/config/<pluginname>.vim`), I would define

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-tab>"`
```

Then, in an ftplugin (`:help ftplugins`, I would use `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vimwiki.vim`), make the change:

```
let b:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
```

---

This type of thing normally works well for dynamic configuration. If UltiSnips creates a mapping when it loads based on this variable (as I suspect it does), it may not be "dynamic"—that is, changing the variable may have no effect. In that case, you will need to find a way to get UltiSnips to change its mappings and such dynamically. Possibly the right combination of `unmap`/`unlet` and `runtime` are enough, but otherwise you might have to add some code to UltiSnips to support a buffer-local trigger and such.